# Confirm on vs confirm

Tags: phrases

Which phrase is grammatically correct?

“Just wanted to confirm that”

Vs

“Just wanted to confirm on that”

I’ve searched up both of them on google and they both seemed to be used so I’m guessing they’re both correct. If they are, what is the difference?

Thanks!!

Comment: `Confirm on` is rarely used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confirm+on%2Cconfirm&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks, just edited alittle bit of the question. Is “Just wanted to confirm on that” also rarely used?

Answer (score 2):

Both are casual and not full sentences.  They are missing a subject.

Confirm is a transitive verb so can take a direct object (which may be a pronoun "that").  No preposition like "on" is needed. There is no common phrasal verb "confirm on".